# Check if a parent has a class, if so apply style to this parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hover over an element, check if the class contains a prefix and if so, apply some style to **this** element. The problem with this, is that if I have a div with a class called "bluescript-contact-form", (notice the prefix "bluescript-") then this does **not fire** when I am hovering over a **child element of this div**. How can this be accomplished?

This is the code I have written so far:

```
var controls = {
  clickedElement: "",
  prefixCheck: function(c){
    // classPrefix = "bluescript-"
    return (c.indexOf(classPrefix) !== -1) ? true : false;
  },
  bindUIActions: (function(){
    $(outputElement).on("load", function(){
      $(outputElement).contents().find("*").on("click", function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      });
      $(outputElement).contents().find("*").mouseenter(function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if(typeof $(this).attr("class") !== "undefined"){
          /* This works, but only on the current element. 
             It does not check if a parent contains a class,
             that contains a prefix that matches. */
          if(controls.prefixCheck($(this).attr("class"))){
            $(this).css({
              outline: onHoverBorder,
              cursor: "pointer"
            });
          }
          /* Else if( a parent contains a class that matches, 
             apply style to THIS parent element ) */
        }
      });
      $(outputElement).contents().find("*").mouseleave(function(e){
        $(this).css({
          outline: "none",
          cursor: "default"
        });
      });
    });
  })()

}
```

I hope this is clear enough. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**stopImmediatePropagation** stops the event from propagating up the DOM tree (It does not reach the parent). If for some reason you need to call that method, you can get the class of the parent node as **$(this).parent().attr("class")** . This code should work fine:

```
else if(controls.prefixCheck($(this).parent().attr("class"))){
    // Your code here
}
```

If you need to change the style of all ancestors whose classes starts with a prefix, you should use the **parents()** method, see:

```
else{
    $(this).parents().each(function(index,value){
        if(controls.prefixCheck($(this).attr("class"))){
            $(this).css({
                outline: "none",
                cursor: "default"
            });
        }
        // Uncomment the next line if you only want to change the first match found.
        // return false ;
    });
}
```

You should use **startsWith** to check the prefix of the class:

```
prefixCheck: function(c){
    // classPrefix = "bluescript-"
    return c.startsWith(classPrefix);
},
```

or use **indexOf** correctly:

```
prefixCheck: function(c){
    // classPrefix = "bluescript-"
    return c.indexOf(classPrefix) === 0;
},
```

Otherwise you may get false positives.

Comment: Does this crawl up for every parent? Or just one? Because I want to check for all of the parents.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra No it doesn't. You can use the parents() method for that purpose. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.